# Build Javascript Object with all names of array and the count

Tags: javascript

Well I have an array like this:

```
const names = ['Josh', 'Travis', 'Josh', 'Travis', 'Brad', 'Travis', 'Josh'];
```

And of this array I'd like to build a Javascript Object.

The key of the object should be the name and the value should be the number of same names in the names array.

The result should look like this then:

```
({"Josh": 3, "Travis": 3, "Brad": 1})
```

And I would like to do it with `reduce`

Comment: It looks line you're taking a test and you want us to solve this problem for you. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const names = ['Josh', 'Travis', 'Josh', 'Travis', 'Brad', 'Travis', 'Josh'];


const count = names.reduce((map, val) => {map[val] = (map[val] || 0)+1; return map}, {} );
    
console.log(count)
```